# Unable to create key under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT in Windows registry

Tags: python, windows, registry

I am facing a weird problem where I am unable to create a key under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.

I have the below code :

```
import win32api
import win32con
import sys


def create_key(access, keyname, perms):
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        try:
            #print "keyname = %s" % keyname
            key = win32api.RegCreateKeyEx(access, keyname, perms, None, 0, None)[0]
            return key
        except Exception, fault:
            print('Error in creating key - %s', fault)

def add_base_key(access, keyname, perms):
    print "in func add_base_key, keyname = %s, perms = %s" %(keyname, perms)
    hkey = create_key(access, keyname, perms)
    print "hkey = %s" % hkey

cls_keyname = ["CLSID\\{8682c35a-98fb-41f3-b65e-693f984caef4}"]

def add_entry():
    try:
        add_base_key(win32con.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, cls_keyname[0], win32con.KEY_ALL_ACCESS )

    except Exception, fault:
        print "fault = %s" %fault

if __name__ == "__main__":
    add_entry()
```

On running this code from cmd prompt using admin rights, I got the below :

```
C:\>python "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\sample.py" in func add_base_key,
keyname = CLSID\{8682c35a-98fb-41f3-b65e-693f984caef4}, perms = 983103
hkey = <PyHKEY:386>
```

However, when I searched the registry entries I am not able to find the key which I have created. Any idea what am I missing here ?

Comment: Probably you're running 32-bit Python, with the CLSID key redirected to `HKCR\Wow6432Node\CLSID`. To write to the non-redirected key from a 32-bit process, add `win32con.KEY_WOW64_64KEY` to the `samDesired` argument.

Comment: But to begin with, *never* modify the registry via `HKCR`. It's a merged view of the `HKLM` and `HKCU` keys. Explicitly create the key in either `HKLM\Software\Classes\CLSID` or `HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID`.

Comment: So, I have added entries in HKLM and HKCU for the keys and sub keys. But, I still don't see the entry in HKCR. Yes, I am running 32 bit Python and for me the samDesired argument's value is win32con.KEY_ALL_ACCESS. If HKCR is the merged view of HKLM and HKCU keys, then shouldn't I see them in HKCR ?

Comment: It's created in `[HKLM|HKCU]\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID` unless you pass `samDesired` as `win32con.KEY_ALL_ACCESS | win32con.KEY_WOW64_64KEY` to bypass the redirection. The merged view (only for reading values) is `HKCR\Wow6432Node\CLSID`. This view prefers `HKCU` over `HKLM`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @eryksun, it works when samDesired argument has a value of win32con.KEY_ALL_ACCESS | win32con.KEY_WOW64_64KEY.